# Start a subshell then run commands

Tags: shell, expect, subshell

Say I have a script that is always run from an interactive shell. I would like this script to launch an interactive subshell that is a replica of the parent (i.e., all environment variables, etc. preserved) and then run arbitrary commands (specifically, I would like to amend `PS1` and define a few aliases). I need a genuine subshell (rather than using `source`, otherwise environment variables won't persist after the script has finished) *and* it needs to be shell agnostic (i.e., works with bash, zsh, etc.)

The only way I've been able to accomplish this, so far, is to launch and script the shell with `expect`. This is a bit horrible, but it sort-of-works:

```
expect <(cat <<-EXPECT
  spawn $SHELL
  send "export FOO=\"$foo\"\r"
  send "PS1=\"(foo:$FOO) \\\$PS1\"\r"
  send "alias foo=\"do_somthing --foo=$FOO\"\r"
  send "clear\r"
  interact
EXPECT)
```

Is there a better way? (I also notice that this approach appears to introduce a problem with the screen redrawing and character encoding.)

The problem with doing something like `PS1="$foo" $SHELL` is that `PS1` can be overridden by the shell's global and user .rc files. There doesn't seem to be a shell agnostic way of providing a custom .rc file.